# How to fix 'DeltaPatcher should receive a base Bundle when being initialized'?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

after adding react-navigation i'm getting error before that working fine

`import {createAppContainer,StackActions,NavigationActions} from 'react-navigation';
    export default class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
               <createAppContainer/>
            </View>
        );
    }
}`

  `const AppNavigator = createStackNavigator({
    Home: {
      screen: HomeScreen,
    },
    Details: {
      screen: DetailsScreen,
    },
  }, {
      initialRouteName: 'Home',
  });`

export default createAppContainer(AppNavigator);

Comment: :))) why did you accept this edit exactly?

Answer (score 1):

For me, I needed to close the metro bundler (not just the Simulator) and then restart it.

Hope this helps someone in the future.

Answer (score 0):

1)Normally this is due to a syntax error in your code. If you go to the terminal where your metro bundler is running and scroll a little bit you can see the exact error.

2) Some time resolving the issue might not help, or there might be no issue at all, in that case, close the chrome (where your app is debugging) and rerun the project( copied from Github).

for me, the error was because of faulty import of components i.e incorrect path or file name, In my case

I was importing like
import xyz from 'Components/xyz'

instead of
import xyz from './Components/xyz'

Such a silly mistake but it wasted my whole day